C++ strcpy() function changes string being copied from
If I say:
char g1[13] = "hello in c++ no"; 
char g2[13];
strcpy(g2, g1);

strcpy() copies g1 into g2, and that's the normal output. But, if I change g2 to a smaller size like g2[7], it changes g1.
Why does g1 change, even though it must change only g2?

even though it must change the size of g2? g2 cant change size.  The size of an array is a compile time constant.

strcpy is notoriously insecure and by copying something larger than the size of the buffer you will experience a buffer overflow. It's quite possible that you overflow g2 into g1 and overwrite data at that location.

strcpy deals in pointers, and pointers are extremely simple. They store an address. They don't know if there really is something at that address or how big it is. As a result strcpy cannot help protect you against overrunning either the source OR destination buffer. strncpy, allows you to pass in a maximum copy size, but can't help you if you get that size wrong or if you come too close for it to be able to store the null terminator.

Side note: don't try to over-stuff g1. A good compiler won't let you: https://godbolt.org/z/6zvq9vKed

Why does g1 change, even though it must change the size of g2?  Get that idea out of your head - arrays in C do not change size.  You set a fixed size in your code when the array is created, and it will never change size.

@user4581301 strncpy, allows you to pass in a maximum copy size Please never recommend strncpy() unless you take the time to explain how strncpy() can fail to terminate the target string.

C++ provides std::string, so you do not have to resort to C library functions that need to be utilized with care.  The code snippet shown does not utilize them with care.

@AndrewHenle Quoting myself above: but can't help you if you get that size wrong or if you come too close for it to be able to store the null terminator. Probably could have worded that better, but I did try to warn.

@AndrewHenle I agree that there are ways to safely use strcpy, but that doesn't change the fact that it's a notoriously dangerous function that has been attributed to countless vulnerabilities. Especially in this case, where the OP didn't understand the implications of their code and used strcpy in an insecure manner. You're caught up in the semantics of our responses instead of offering the OP an explanation yourself. strcpy is notoriously dangerous due to common misuse and severe implications. Blaming programmers that misuse it doesn't change that fact.

The typical solution I've seen is to never call strcpy() or strncpy() (or any function that modifies a C-string) directly, but instead a wrapper function that guarantees a null character. C-strings are such a pain, and I loathe them.

Where do you see C++ in here?...

@Super-intelligentShade • the question had been tagged with c++, and the title had C++ (which now is C).  That tag has since been removed, and the title changed.

@Super-intelligentShade The OP's code is perfectly valid (but incorrect and incomplete because it lacks the #include being used) C++. The OP tagged C++ because that is the language they are learning. Who are you to decide to change the title and the tag? Having done so, you have invalidated several comments and one of the answers given below that respond as a C++ person would. Suggest you remedy YOUR mistake.

@Super-intelligentShade I see it right here: "hello in c++ no";.

For future reference, please include a [mre] in your question. The code in your question is a fragment, and we can't be sure that it matches the code that you compiled.

You have a buffer overflow.  You are copying more data into g2 than it can hold.  strcpy() does not perform any bounds checking,  and so in this example it will exceed the bounds of g2 and write into surrounding memory. Thus g1 may change if it follows g2 in memory.  A compiler is free to order local variables however it wants.  Just because you declare g1 before g2 does not guarantee that g2 actually follows g1 in memory.  In your case, the opposite is likely true (use your compiler's debugger to verify).

And even if g1 comes before g2, g1 is declared as 13 characters but assigned a string that takes 16 characters to store. g2 could potentially point to the middle of g1's data (although I'd expect the compiler to flag this as an error).

If you say:
char g1[13] = "hello in c++ no"; 

then your program is ill-formed and will most likely not even compile. g++ gives me:
c.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
c.cpp:5:19: error: initializer-string for ‘char [13]’ is too long [-fpermissive]
    5 |     char g1[13] = "hello in c++ no";
      |         

At the very least, I'd expect a compile-time warning, which you absolutely should not ignore.
The string "hello in c++ no" is 15 characters long, with a 16th byte required to hold the null terminator '\0'.
You could write code similar to what's in your question that would compile successfully, for example by giving g1 a size of at least 16 (or omitting the size and letting the compiler figure out how long it needs to be:
char g1[] = "hello in c++ no";

Then the strcpy call would have undefined behavior, since you're copying more data than can fit into the target g2. The compiler is not required to diagnose this error, but the language standard says nothing about what the code will do. One likely outcome is that the call will clobber other memory, perhaps some of the memory that makes up g1. Or it could crash. Or it could appear to work without error, which is the worst outcome, since it means you have a bug that's going to be difficult to diagnose.
Using C++'s std::string rather than raw C-style strings makes it much easier to avoid this kind of problem.

your program is ill-formed That does make me wonder how the code is being compiled - and if it's really C++ and not C.

@AndrewHenle Even if it's compiled as C, it violates a constraint (C's equivalent of "ill-formed"). It happens that gcc by default issues a non-fatal warning, whereas g++ treats it as a fatal error. My guess is that the OP had some similar code that actually exhibits the issue, then tried to narrow it down but didn't try to compile the reduced version. But that's only a guess.
